# Self constrained elements in generic rest parameter

Tags: typescript

Typescript can infer tuple types for generic rest parameters constrained by array type. But this doesn't work in my case. I am trying to pass a series of pairs `[function, argument]` and would like to type-check that argument and function types do match. Is it possible?

```
type User = {
    name: string
    age: number
}

function eatNumber(a: number) { }
function eatString(a: string) { }
function eatUser(a: User) { }

type FuncAndArg<F extends (arg: any) => void> = [F, Parameters<F>[0]]

function callMany<F extends (arg: any) => void, T extends FuncAndArg<F>[]>(...pairs: T) { }

const jack = {
    name: 'jack',
    age: 23
}

//argument type not checked
callMany([eatNumber, jack], [eatString, jack], [eatUser, jack])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with rest arguments.  The way I'd represent this is with a generic tuple representing the types of the second element in each parameter to `callMany()`, specify the `pairs` argument as a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), and rely on [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to have the compiler infer `T`.  Like this:

```
function callMany<T extends any[]>(
  ...pairs: { [I in keyof T]: [(a: T[I]) => any, T[I]] }
) { }
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
callMany([eatNumber, jack], [eatString, jack], [eatUser, jack]); // error!
//        ~~~~~~~~~ <-- User not assignable to number

callMany([eatNumber, 23], [eatString, jack], [eatUser, jack]); // error!
//                          ~~~~~~~~~ <-- User not assignable to string

callMany([eatNumber, 23], [eatString, "jack"], [eatUser, jack]); // okay
```

Looks like what you want.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqA7AQwFsIAuKOYRASzwHNtcC6z8BXIgIyUwF9NMAMzZ4AxsGoB7PFAgFgAOQ7dEACgLk8ypAEoMUfsLETps+QGUqtOuvKUa9PegNCR4qTLnB4SW7ASITi6uxh5QogQANpEAsgR4IAA8ACqyAB7AEHgAJnBQ8SAA2gC6AHyqAHRVYATUiHDkzoUAklC0UADWECCSglDJxeSFfsktxXoopfkJADT9Y8UGQfyYotKUUABWBKId5D7IaFi4+MSsAOTbu+czjDjMrABMAMx8AhHRcQmqhV5KXEg5lcOsU5r8LFZ6ECdiCwV4DtDduMANxQAD0aNkiEQkkQAEJMBiTicAH5k8nkqCJAC01P8SHwkmA+TgcGodEInEi0GAknYAMQ7yisQKPz+2kQcxeoKg4OAlgcdERsNl8ICypR6MxSBx+MJmOJhqNRoppqptPpyDwTJZbI5BC5PL59msQs+orl-xUUueMrlCuscwARMCg361YCtjDNUTJB0CCBMEA)

Comment: nice, didn't think you could grab the args like that.